# Dow Jones Industrial Average (DJIA), NASDAQ 100, and S&P 500 index historical membership listing?

Tags: historical-data, market-indexes

Can anyone point me to a listing of historical Dow, NASDAQ 100, and maybe even S&P 500 members?

Answer (score 2):

Dow Jones:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_components_of_the_Dow_Jones_Industrial_Average

NASDAQ:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASDAQ-100 (scroll down)

S&P

Tricky. From what I can find, you need to be in Harvard Business School, a member of CRSP, or have access to Bloomberg's databases. S&P did have the info available years ago, but no longer that I can find.